# how to show a particular div in a cshtml MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to show a particular div of a cshtml.
There are 4 div having different id, And there are some sub menus of a menu which link to a particular div of this cshtml.
I want to pass some flag with href of an anchor so that my ActionResult will keep track of that flag and so the div belongs to that flag.

```
   <div id="POS" class="content" style="margin: auto;">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 5px;">Profile of Society</h1>
    <p style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px;">

    </p>
    <p style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px;">

       >
    </p>
</div>
<div id="Ms" class="content">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 5px;">Mission
    </h1>
    <p style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px;">


    </p>
    <p style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px;">

    </p>
</div>

<div id="VSN" class="content">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 5px;">Vision</h1>
    <p style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px;">

    </p>
    <p style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px;">

    </p>
</div>
<div id="Aim" class="content">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 5px;">Aims & Objectives
    </h1>
</div>
<div id="CoreV" class="content">
    <h1 style="margin-left: 5px;">Core Values</h1>
    <p style="margin-left: 8px; margin-right: 8px;">          

    </p>

</div>
```

here we have 5 div . I want to show a div at a time .

```
 <li class="navText"><a id="A11" href="@Url.Action("AboutUs", "Home")">About Us</a>
        <ul class="site-search-enabled">            
           <li class="navSubText"><a id="A1" href="@Url.Action("AboutUs", "Home", new { Type =  
"POS" })">Profile of Society</a></li>                 
            <li class="navSubText"><a id="A3" href="@Url.Action("AboutUs", "Home", new { Type =  
 "Ms" })">Mission</a></li>
            <li class="navSubText"><a id="A4" href="@Url.Action("AboutUs", "Home", new { Type = 
 "VSN" })">Vision</a></li>
            <li class="navSubText"><a id="A5" href="@Url.Action("AboutUs", "Home", new { Type = 
 "Aim" })">Aims & Objectives</a></li>
            <li class="navSubText"><a id="A6" href="@Url.Action("AboutUs", "Home", new { Type = 
 "CoreV" })">Core Values</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

 public ActionResult AboutUs(string type)
    {
        // rou
        ViewBag.Type = type;
        return View();
    }
```

This is the calling of each div What should be i send with my href so that it will keep some fleg . and how i will get that flag on the called views.

Comment: What specific problem are you having with this?

Comment: You need to include some html and code to put this in context.